# Not able to connect Salesforce using Soap API/ WSC connector

Tags: soap-api, metadata-api, eclipse, enterprise-wsdl, wsc

I am trying to connect salesforce using WSC connector. I have created the metadata.jar file, enterprise.jar file etc.

I am getting the connection error. It is working in an open network, but now working in a private network. I have set the proxy settings also in Eclipse tool, but still not working.

Does anyone knows, what is the issue?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Error Snapshot in eclips]

Comment: the connection is timing out for some reason

Comment: Check the login history and see if your request reaches Salesforce. If yes then try to increase the session timeout.

Comment: It doesn't reaches to salesforce